# Custom field in office 365 user profile

Tags: user-profile-service, office-365

I need to create different types of custom fields in user profile in office 365. From office 365 administration i am able to add text box type filed in user profile under a new section and working fine. But problem is i need to add choice and drop down type filed and i didn't find any option like this. If anyone know how to add choice type field in user profile please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind the property to a Managed Metadata term set.  In the property settings section, check "Configure a term set for this property", and then select the term set from the drop down:

[image]